# JavaScript typing speed calculator

Tags: javascript, game, timer

I would like to kindly ask to review my code. I'd like suggestions, criticisms, and discussions on what is good and what could be done better.

```js
const wordsArray = [ "aardvark", "albatross", "alligator", "alpaca", "ant", "anteater", "antelope", "ape", "armadillo", "donkey", "baboon", "badger", "barracuda", "bat", "bear", "beaver", "bee", "bison", "boar", "buffalo", "butterfly", "camel", "capybara", "caribou", "cassowary", "cat", "caterpillar", "cattle", "chamois", "cheetah", "chicken", "chimpanzee", "chinchilla", "chough", "clam", "cobra", "cockroach", "cod", "cormorant", "coyote", "crab", "crane", "crocodile", "crow", "curlew", "deer", "dinosaur", "dog", "dogfish", "dolphin", "dotterel", "dove", "dragonfly", "duck", "dugong", "dunlin", "eagle", "echidna", "eel", "eland", "elephant", "elk", "emu", "falcon", "ferret", "finch", "fish", "flamingo", "fly", "fox", "frog", "gaur", "gazelle", "gerbil", "giraffe", "gnat", "gnu", "goat", "goldfinch", "goldfish", "goose", "gorilla", "goshawk", "grasshopper", "grouse", "guanaco", "gull", "hamster", "hare", "hawk", "hedgehog", "heron", "herring", "hippopotamus", "hornet", "horse", "human", "hummingbird", "hyena", "ibex", "ibis", "jackal", "jaguar", "jay", "jellyfish", "kangaroo", "kingfisher", "koala", "kookabura", "kouprey", "kudu", "lapwing", "lark", "lemur", "leopard", "lion", "llama", "lobster", "locust", "loris", "louse", "lyrebird", "magpie", "mallard", "manatee", "mandrill", "mantis", "marten", "meerkat", "mink", "mole", "mongoose", "monkey", "moose", "mosquito", "mouse", "mule", "narwhal", "newt", "nightingale", "octopus", "okapi", "opossum", "oryx", "ostrich", "otter", "owl", "oyster", "panther", "parrot", "partridge", "peafowl", "pelican", "penguin", "pheasant", "pig", "pigeon", "pony", "porcupine", "porpoise", "quail", "quelea", "quetzal", "rabbit", "raccoon", "rail", "ram", "rat", "raven", "reindeer", "rhinoceros", "rook", "salamander", "salmon", "sandpiper", "sardine", "scorpion", "seahorse", "seal", "shark", "sheep", "shrew", "skunk", "snail", "snake", "sparrow", "spider", "spoonbill", "squid", "squirrel", "starling", "stingray", "stinkbug", "stork", "swallow", "swan", "tapir", "tarsier", "termite", "tiger", "toad", "trout", "turkey", "turtle", "viper", "vulture", "wallaby", "walrus", "wasp", "weasel", "whale", "wildcat", "wolf", "wolverine", "wombat", "woodcock", "woodpecker", "worm", "wren", "yak", "zebra" ];

const inputs = document.querySelector('.input');
const wordsContainer = document.querySelector('.wordsContainer')
let clickSum = 0;
let wordsSum = 0;
let currentWord = 0;
let timeStart = true;
const time = 30; // seconds

function displayWords(array) {
  wordsContainer.innerHTML = array.map( (value) => {return `<span class='word'>${value}</span>`}).join('');
}

function addActive() {
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.word');
  spans.item(currentWord).classList.add('active');
}

function removeActive() {
  document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
}

function onFlyCheck() {
  const span = document.querySelector('.active');
  const wordSpell = span.textContent.split('');
  const inputSpell = this.value.split('');
  const output = wordSpell.map( (value) => `<span>${value}</span>`);

  if (inputSpell.length > wordSpell.length) return;

  inputSpell.map( (value, index) => {
    if (wordSpell[index] === value) output[index] = `<span class="correct">${wordSpell[index]}</span>`;
    else output[index] = `<span class="incorrect">${wordSpell[index]}</span>`
  });
  span.innerHTML = output.join('');
}

function commitWord(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 32 || e.keyCode === 13) {
    checkWord(this.value.trim());
    this.value = "";
  } 
}

function checkWord(word) {
  const active = document.querySelector('.active');
  active.innerHTML = wordsArray[currentWord];
  
  if (word === wordsArray[currentWord]) {
    active.classList.add('correct');
    wordsSum++;
    clickSum += (wordsArray[currentWord].length);
  } else {
    active.classList.add('incorrect')
  }

  currentWord++;
  removeActive();
  addActive();
  scrollWords();
}

function startTime() {
  if (timeStart) countDown();
  timeStart = false
}

function countDown() {
  setTimeout( endGame, time*1000);
}


function endGame() {
  const cpm = clickSum / time * 60;
  const score = document.querySelector('.score');
  inputs.disabled = true;

  score.innerHTML = `Congratulations! Your score is ... <br>
    <p>${cpm} key press per minute </p>
    <p>${wordsSum} correct word(s). </p> 
    <p> Refresh page (F5) to start again </p>`
}

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length; i; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
    [array[i-1], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i-1]];
  }
}

let offset = 0;

function scrollWords() {
  const active = document.querySelector('.active');

  if (active.offsetTop -offset > active.offsetHeight) {
    offset += active.offsetHeight;
    wordsContainer.style.top =`-${offset}px`;
  }
}

inputs.addEventListener('keyup', onFlyCheck);
inputs.addEventListener('keyup', commitWord);
inputs.addEventListener('keypress', startTime);

shuffle(wordsArray);

displayWords(wordsArray);
addActive();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Type speed calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="wordsContainer">Loading sentence...</div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <div class="score"></div>
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

<style>
  body {
    background-color: #ff6c00;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .wrapper{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 75px auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .wordsContainer{
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.2s; 
  }
  .container{
    text-align: center;
     /* padding: 1rem 2rem 0;  */
    width:100%;
    height: 10rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 1rem 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffc500;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  input{
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .currentWord{
    background-color: white;
  }
  .word{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }
  .active{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: .25em;
  }
  .incorrect{
    color: red;
  }
  .correct{
    color: green;
  }
  .score{
    margin: 125px auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### forEach their own

```
  inputSpell.map( (value, index) => {
    if (wordSpell[index] === value) output[index] = `<span class="correct">${wordSpell[index]}</span>`;
    else output[index] = `<span class="incorrect">${wordSpell[index]}</span>`
  });
```

Avoid using `Array#map` for side effects. If you don't care about the return value, use `Array#forEach` instead; it's more clear to the reader, and doesn't build up a temporary results array.

Minimizing the scope of the conditional could also be nice, depending on your taste:

```
inputSpell.forEach((value, i) => {
  const word = wordSpell[i];
  output[i] = `<span class="${word === value ? 'correct' : 'incorrect'}">${word}</span>`
});
```

`index` is a fine name; I've used `i` here since the function is so small and it's also a standard name.

---

#### Remove the magic

```
function commitWord(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 32 || e.keyCode === 13) {
```

32 and 13 are "magic numbers"; factoring them out into named constants would be good. Plenty of people know that 13 is the enter key, but `e.keyCode === KEYS.Enter` requires no thought at all.

Also, `.active` is a class name that appears a handful of times. Once you see it two or three times, it's a good candidate for moving into a variable -- that prevents you from misspelling it and makes it easier to change in the future.

---

#### Implicits and organization

```
function displayWords(array) {
  wordsContainer.innerHTML = array.map( (value) => {return `<span class='word'>${value}</span>`}).join('');
}
```

Elsewhere you've used the implicit-return syntax, and it works here too. A more descriptive name than `array` would also be good.

```
function displayWords(words) {
  wordsContainer.innerHTML = words.map(word => `<span class="word">${word}</span>`).join('');
}
```

---

```
let offset = 0;
```

This is adrift near the bottom between a bunch of function declarations. Ideally it would go up top with the rest of the variables.

---

To jump into the HTML for a second, this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

can safely drop the `type` attribute; it's assumed by essentially every browser.

Also, the `<style>` should go in the `<head>`, either directly as-is or via a `<link rel="stylesheet">`.

---

### Cohesion

A class may help organize your state more clearly.

Switching over would require

- prefixing most things with `this`
- changing some selections on `document` to be on the `wordsContainer` (optional, but in the spirit of reusability)

but it would provide some good encapsulation, more clearly showing what is/affects the game state and what is just utility methods. It would also likely be nicer to work with as you grow more features.

Here's a partial translation to a class approach for the sake of discussion:

```
const KEYS = Object.freeze({
  Enter: 13,
  Space: 32,
});

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length; i; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
    [array[i-1], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i-1]];
  }
}

class TypingSpeed {
  constructor({ inputSelector, containerSelector }) { 
    this.$input = document.querySelector(inputSelector);
    this.$container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
    this.wordClass = 'word';
    this.words = TypingSpeed.getWords();
    this.offset = 0;

    this.$input.addEventListener('keyup', this.onFlyCheck.bind(this));
    this.$input.addEventListener('keyup', thus.commitWord.bind(this));
    this.$input.addEventListener('keypress', this.startTime.bind(this));

    shuffle(this.words);

    this.displayWords(this.words);
    this.addActive();
  }

  // Pulled into a method to (a) clear up the constructor
  // and (b) you may want to eg. load from a json file
  static getWords() {
    return [.......];
  }

  displayWords(words) {
    this.$container.innerHTML = words.map(word => `<span class="${this.wordClass}">${word}</span>`).join('');
  }

  addActive() {
    const spans = this.$container.querySelectorAll(`${this.wordClass}`);
    spans.item(this.currentWord).classList.add('active');
  }

  ...
}
```

---

Really this looks nice in general. React and friends have their place, but it's fun to see straightforward use of `querySelector`, template string HTML, etc in a lightweight project like this.

Comment: Thank you BenC for your detail feedback. Class approach is not clear to me, could you advise any good materials?